# Maximising browser affects text alignment

Tags: css

I have a problem that I have not been able to find any solution to anywhere, if somebody could help me out here I'd be truly grateful.

On this page, I have 3 links scrolling to sections lower on the page. For each section there are 3 lines of white text in alignment with some arrow graphics. Everything is fine until the browser is maximised and fills the screen resulting in displacement of the white text and the main black heading within the circle graphic by about 10 pixels.

I can not figure out why this is happening, and am truly stumped. Here's a link to the test site and page in question.
http://surefireresearchtestsite.businesscatalyst.com/ourApproach.html

```
HTML

<div class="bgImageOverTop">

    <div class="wrapperTwo">

    <div  class="ourApproach ">  

        <div class="feedsBox " id="scopeControl">

        <h3 id="scope">Scope</h3>
        <div class="scopeFeedsBox">
            <ul>
                <li>Your Business</li>
                <li>Your Marketing Goals</li>
                <li>The Competitive Market</li>                   
            </ul>                                   
        </div>               
       </div>

    <div class="feedsBox" id="strategyControl">
    <!-- similar thing happening here -->               
    </div>


    <div class="feedsBox" id="executeControl">                   
    <!-- similar thing happening here -->               
    </div>

  </div>
 </div>
</div>

CSS

.bgImageOverTop{
    width:100%;
    height:3000px;
    background: url("../images/midSection-Approach.png") 50% 50% no-repeat;   
    background-size: cover;
    position:relative;
    z-index:50;
}
.wrapperTwo{
    width:886px;
    padding-left:33px;
    padding-right:33px;
    margin:auto;
    height:2950px;
    position:relative;
    top:0px;
    z-index:1500;
}

.ourApproach{
    float:left;
    text-align:center;
    font-family: 'rudaregular';
    height:auto;
    margin-top:130px;   
    padding:0 10px 0px 10px;
    position:relative;
    z-index:1500;
}
.feedsBox{
    width:auto;
    height:auto;
    position:relative;
    z-index:50;
}
#scopeControl{
    position:relative;
    top:432px;
    left:263px;
}
#scope{
    position:relative;
    top:0px;
}
.scopeFeedsBox{
    width:210px;
    height:auto;
    line-height:1em;
    position:relative;
    top:-70px;
    left:270px;
}
.scopeFeedsBox ul{
    float:left;
    list-style-type:none;
}
.scopeFeedsBox ul li {
    float:left;
    width:210px;
    display:inline;
    font-size:.9em;
    line-height:1.2em;
    text-align:left;
}
```

Comment: Could you explain your problem more detailed, please? I'm not sure if I understand it correctly hence I can't reproduce it.

Comment: Sure. You will need to click on the down arrow in the footer first, or select the 'Scope" link. Then - when the browser is maximised to fill the screen by clicking the box icon next to the "close the browser icon" (top right), the 3 lines of headings text sitting inside the arrows flowing to the circle lose their correct positioning.

Comment: Define _correct position_ please. Right know I see all three lines of text aligned to the left with approx. 5px padding from the left (between first letter and end of a short line going from the circle) and about 15px padding from the right (between last letter in line and arrowhead). How should they look like?
Can you also tell me what screen resolution you have?

Comment: What you describe is the correct positioning for the text in the arrow graphic, but when the browser is maximised to fill your screen, all 3 lines of that text, and the main section's heading in the circle, drop by about 15 pixels. My screen resolution is 1920 x 1200. I'm not sure that this has anything to do with it as the problem has been reported on other varied screen resolutions. Thanks again for your attention to this problem of mine.

Comment: My browser was maximised when I tested it. I have 1920x1080px resolution. Let's dig deeper - what browser did you test this in (name and version)?

Comment: Tested in Firefox 23 & 24, Safari 5.1.7, Chrome 29, IE 10, 9 and 8 (IE 8 is the only browser that displays correctly in maximised mode).

Comment: When maximised, if I remove float:left from .scopeFeedsBox ul the problem disappears but the problem then appears in the non-maximised state.